# Want to check if input x (having 5 columns) have different output y in python

Tags: python, dictionary

My dataframe has 1000 rows with 6 column values. first 5 being x and 6th is y. I have already dropped duplicates and Nan values and pre-processed. I want to check now row by row that for same x (all 5 columns values in x) is there a different y value in the dataframe. (expected sample output is as below )

X(Ram -- Rahim -- Robert  -- Robin -- Roller) ------y(Religion)

X(Ram -- Rahim -- Robert  -- Robin -- Roller) ------y(God)

Comment: try to groupby multiple columns https://jamesrledoux.com/code/group-by-aggregate-pandas